# How to get traffic source data in real time from a user session

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

Our site has a form that, when filled out, pushes the users data to our CRM.

I want to push the Source/Medium and Campaign from GA for that user/session to the CRM when they complete the form.

We're able to get session data for users via the Google Analytics reporting api, but the data does not seem to be available in real-time.

Are there any other approaches that would work or any tips for how to do this?

Comment: Have the form API to return a user ID or some sort of ID on successful submission, capture it as a custom dimension in GA, then merge the two sets of data. 

Users are tagged with a campaign for different amounts of time depending on your GA settings, also they're tagged with the campaign across multiple sessions. So cookie-based solutions wouldn't give you good coverage.

Answer (score 0):

The Google analytics reporting api does not have real time data.  Any data that is returned that is under 48 hours old has probably not completed processing. You should  check the isgolden fields returned it will tell you if that data is done processing.

I think you should be using the [google analytics reporting real time api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) this will give you limited data but realtime.  Its very limited but its what they can be sure has completed processing.